# *Efficiently* moving dataframes from Pandas to R with RPy (or other means)

Tags: python, r, dataframe, rpy2

I have a dataframe in Pandas, and I want to do some statistics on it using R functions. No problem! RPy makes it easy to send a dataframe from Pandas into R:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(100000),columns=range(100))
from rpy2 import robjects as ro
ro.globalenv['df'] = df
```

And if we're in IPython:

```
%load_ext rmagic
%R -i df
```

For some reason the `ro.globalenv` route is slightly slower than the `rmagic` route, but no matter. What matters is this: The dataframe I will ultimately be using is ~100GB. This presents a few problems:

1. Even with just 1GB of data, the transfer is rather slow.
2. If I understand correctly, this creates two copies of the dataframe in memory: one in Python, and one in R. That means I'll have just doubled my memory requirements, and I haven't even gotten to running statistical tests!

Is there any way to:

1. transfer a large dataframe between Python and R more quickly?
2. Access the same object in memory? I suspect this asking for the moon.

Comment: That's an interesting question - I usually end up writing my data to the disk and then read them again in R. Needless to say, this is far from efficient. However `python` and `R` are completely different languages. It's already amazing that something like `rpy` is possible in python. I doubt that it's possible to have some data frame data structure that works for both  python and R without the need of major transformations. Looking forward to answers, though.

Comment: Can you write to `.RData` file from Pandas?

Comment: Probably not without converting to a `R` data frame first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rpy2` is using a conversion mechanism that is trying to avoid copying objects when moving between Python and R. However, this is currently only working in the direction R -> Python.

Python has an interface called the "buffer interface" that is used by `rpy2` and that lets it minimize the number of copies for the C-level compatible between R and Python (see http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.5/html/numpy.html#from-rpy2-to-numpy - the doc seems outdated as the `__array_struct__` interface is no longer the primary choice).

There is no equivalent to the buffer interface in R, and the current concern holding me back from providing an equivalent functionality in `rpy2` is the handling of borrowed references during garbage collection (and the lack of time to think sufficiently carefully about it).

So in summary there is a way to share data between Python and R without copying but this will require to have the data created in R.

Comment: Thanks! Will this work for a Pandas `DataFrame`? That is, creating a `data.frame` in R and then sending it to Python to use as a `DataFrame`? What would the relevant commands be?

Comment: Looking at the code for `pandas2ri.ri2py_dataframe` and `numpy2ri.ri2py_list`, it looks like this does _not_ happen by default for sending a `data.frame` to Python? Is that correct?

Comment: `pandas2ri.ri2py_dataframe` is first using the `numpy` converter, and will try to turn the R list (R data frames inherit from lists) into a numpy data structure using `numpy.rec.fromarrays`. An alternative would be to first create a numpy `recarray` and populate it using `numpy.asarray(column_in_R_dataframe)`.

Comment: I don't quite follow. It sounds like you're saying that no, `ri2py_dataframe` doesn't handle the data copying as we would want. But I don't see how the proposed alternative accomplishes the task. Won't creating the `recarray` just also create a copy?

Comment: First create a initial minimal `recarray` matching the data frame, then populate each of its cells (columns) with the result of `asarray`.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, [`feather`](https://github.com/wesm/feather) seems to be the most efficient option for data-interchange between DataFrame of R and pandas.